# on click for append into my custom litghtbox plugin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom jquery plugin style lightbox this work fine with static elements, but if I add elements with append from InifiteScroll, i wan t fix my custom plugin for support append a function for example reload, i dont have idea really how made this,

this is the plugin, very simply:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.MyLightbox = function(opt){
       var settings, createBox, closeModal, body;

       settings = $.extend({
           'modal': 'jquery-modal',
           'close': 'jquery-modal-close',
           'CloseText': 'X',
           'shade': 'jquery-modal-shade'
       }, opt);

       body = $('body');

       closeModal = function(modal, shade){
           modal.remove();
           shade.remove();
       };

       createBox = function(data){
           var shade, close, modal;

           shade = $('<div />',{
              class: settings.shade 
           }).on('click', function(){
              //close modal and shade
               closeModal(modal, shade);
           });

           close = $('<a />', {
               text: settings.CloseText,
               class: settings.close,
               href: '#'
           }).on('click',function(e){
               closeModal(modal, shade);
               e.preventDefault();
           });

           modal = $('<div />',{
              html: data,
               class: settings.modal
           }).append(close);

           body.prepend(shade, modal);
       };

       this.on('click', function(e){
           var self = $(this);
           var url = self.attr('href');

           $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: 'get',
               cache: false
           }).done(function(data){
               createBox(data);
           }).error(function(data){
               createBox('The content that you want see is not avaliable, sorry');
           });
           e.preventDefault();
       });

   };

})(jQuery);
```

And I call this with:

```
    $('.pin-data').MyLightbox({
        'modal': 'modal-window',
       'close': 'modal-close',
       'CloseText': 'X',
       'shade': 'modal-shade' 
    });
```

Thanks so much!
Regards!